# Using link instead of submit input to submit form in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a submit button:

```
<form method="post" action="" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
</form>
```

I'd like to change the button to an a href:

```
<form method="post" action="" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
    <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();">Delete</a>
</form>
```

However, I dont know how to attribute the name="delete" to it

Comment: i want to submit the form through a text link

Comment: you can do this via css make submit button look like link is possible with css

Comment: make a hidden field with `name="delete"`

Comment: What's the jQuery code you already have (to make an `a` out of the `input`)? To set arbitrary attributes, there's jQuery.attr: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: make this submit button hidden and click programmatically

Comment: Just make an anchor tag, bind to the click event, and make an ajax request when it is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input type="submit" actually post you form. but if you use anchor instead of "submit" button, then you have to do something else, since it will not post your form.In this case you can use a trick.

```
  <form method="post" action="" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="submit" style="display:none;" name="delete" value="Delete">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('input:submit').click();">Delete</a>
 </form>
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just bind to the click event of your link.

```
<a href="" id="deleteLink">Delete</a>



$('#deleteLink').click(function(evt) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/delete"
      method: "post",
      data: 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" style="display:none;">
    <a href="#" id="linkDel">Delete</a>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('linkDel').click(function(){

$(this).closest('input[type="submit"]').click();

})
```

Comment: interesting, but if the form is submitted through another button or href would the hidden field be always passed?

Comment: no, the submit button which one is clicked will be passed

Comment: but in hidden field case it will always be posted

Comment: ok i understand the logic, that seems good, I think there is a problem with quotes in onclik

Comment: yeah but in first I got : SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Comment: then i will go with seperate event instead of inline see edit

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="Delete">
    <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();">Delete</a>
</form>
```

Just type hidden your input.

Comment: the problem is  that the hidden field is pass with any other submit button what is not enviable